# How to include opencv source files as a cmake dependency without installing it?

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, build, cmake

I have opencv installed in my system but I do not want to use the installed version. The installed version (from distro repository) was compiled with gcc 7.

I want to compile a C++ project with opencv and dlib as dependency using older gcc compiler installed in a separate path. I have downloaded the opencv sources and extracted it into a seperate folder. What is the proper way to include it cmake so that it is compiled and included as a dependency during compilation?

This is my project structure.

```
projects/
  |--> project1/
  |      |--> main.cpp
  |      |--> CMakeLists.txt
  |
  |--> dlib/
  |
  |--> opencv-3.3.1/
```

My CMakeLists.txt looks like this.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)

project(project1)
add_subdirectory(../dlib/dlib dlib_build)
add_subdirectory(../opencv-3.3.1/dlib opencv_build)

add_executable(project1 main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(project1 dlib::dlib opencv)
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to run a cmake project using a different gcc than is installed on your system?  Or that you want to compile with sources of opencv that are separate from what is installed on your system?

Comment: The system has gcc7 installed and also a version of opencv compiled with gcc7 installed.

I don't want to use either of them as I need cuda support. I have gcc6 installed in a different path that I am using by setting the CC and CXX variables at terminal.

I want to use opencv in my project but I can't use the installed one, so I need to include opencv from source as dependency.

Answer (score 0):

To specify a different compiler, pass in the -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER -DCMAKE_CC_COMPILER  parameters in to cmake, each referencing the appropriate path and command.

When you are adding sources within the add_library function, tell it exactly where the sources are.
so...

```
list(${CUSTOM_OPENCV} APPEND
"/custom/path/source1.cpp"
"/custom/path/source2.cpp"
)

add_library(my_app ${CUSTOM_OPENCV})
```

That might be how I would do it.  You might even want to pass in the custom path through a cmake parameter to make your project a little more robust for future uses.

Comment: I have edited  my question to more clearly explain the problem. I am setting the compiler as gcc6 by temporarily changing the CC and CXX variables in the shell and it works well. Also dlib is being built and included without a problem. Its only opencv that I am not able to include properly. The findpackage method that is commonly used finds the opencv that I have already installed in the system which I do not want to use.